# Gson remove header from Json

Tags: json, scala, solr, gson

I have a Json that i have created using Gson using below

```
val gson = new Gson
val jsonString = gson.toJson(mydata).
println(jsonString)
```

here is the output

```
  {"mydata":{"date":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
  "pdf:PDFVersion":["1.6"],
  "pdf:docinfo:title":[" PDF Test Page"],
  "xmp:CreatorTool":["Acrobat PDFMaker 7.0.7 for Word"],
  "Company":["Government of Yukon"],
  "access_permission:modify_annotations":["false"],
  "access_permission:can_print_degraded":["true"],
  "dc:creator":["Yukon","Canada","Yukon Department of Education"],
  "language":["EN-US"],
  "dcterms:created":["2008-06-04T22:44:00Z"],
  "Last-Modified":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
  "dcterms:modified":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
  "dc:format":["application/pdf; version\u003d1.6"],
  "title":[" PDF Test Page"],
   }
   }
```

Desired output

```
  {"date":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
  "pdf:PDFVersion":["1.6"],
  "pdf:docinfo:title":[" PDF Test Page"],
  "xmp:CreatorTool":["Acrobat PDFMaker 7.0.7 for Word"],
  "Company":["Government of Yukon"],
  "access_permission:modify_annotations":["false"],
  "access_permission:can_print_degraded":["true"],
  "dc:creator":["Yukon","Canada","Yukon Department of Education"],
  "language":["EN-US"],
  "dcterms:created":["2008-06-04T22:44:00Z"],
  "Last-Modified":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
  "dcterms:modified":["2008-06-04T22:47:36Z"],
  "dc:format":["application/pdf; version\u003d1.6"],
  "title":[" PDF Test Page"],
   }
```

I would like to know on how i may be able to remove the header ({"mydata":) and footer (}) form the above json so that i may use to add a record to Solr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper `mydata` may be removed with Gson's API by converting the initial object into a JSON tree (and not into a String as tried in the question) and then transforming the contents of `mydata` node into a JSON string. This is quite easy:

```
val jsonTree = gson.toJsonTree(mydata)
val mydataNode = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("mydata")
val jsonString = gson.toJson(mydataNode) // jsonString contains the desired output
```

P.S. the comma `,` after `"title":[" PDF Test Page"],` in the original json should be removed, otherwise it is invalid.